# Using a foreach across multiple tables

Tags: php

So, I have a database table called customers. The last 6 products they have purchased is stored in the customer table under "p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 and p6". The product would then be stored as the product number, eg

```
Last Purchased:
   p1: 12355
   p2: 55142
   p3: 51251
```

etc. These products all have they're own table row in the "Products" table. On that list is amongst others "price". Now, what I would like to do is an somewhat easy way to extract the biggest purchase amongst the last 6 purchases. Getting the biggest is easy by using the `max()`
command, and I could do something like the whole

```
$p1 = $array[0]["p1"];
$array = $db->queryA("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product = $p1");
```

and then compare them as in max($p1,$p2,$p3) etc. My problem is this would take an enormous amount of time and code. Is there a better way of doing this, for instance with an foreach loop? I am really sorry, but I am completely stomped. Again.. All help is appreciated. :)

Edit: not sure how to display the table structure, but here goes my attempt, sorry if it is bad :(

```
customers            products
   id                      prod_nr     
   name                    name
   mail                    price
   member_since            quantity
   p1
   p2
   p3
   p4
   p5
   p6
```

Would this suffice? It is some more fields, but it is the gist of it. Also, "id" and "prod_nr" are primaries

edit nr2: also wanted to explain that I have about 11 of these 6* queries I would like to run, so as to not making you think I'm just wasting your time instead of a little of mine... :)

Edit again, here is the part of the database provider giving me problems...

```
    public function query($query)
{
    try{
        $query = trim($query);
        $sth = $this->pdo->query($query,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = null;
        foreach($sth as $row) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        return $result != null ? json_encode($result) : null;
    }
    catch(exception $e)
    {
        echo('Exception ' . $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: Tried :) Will do it something else if it's not what you had in mind :)

Comment: no no no no your database schema isn't good. You should not store the latest 6 products like that. You need a table to store all the purchases (at least these columns: customer id, product id, quantity and timestamp) and then write a JOIN with the required constraints (order by, and limit 6 are your friends)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is all the items to an array, and then implode it so it uses single quotes and then execute a query like this:

```
$array = $db->queryA("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product IN($your_array)");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need is redesign your database you need a purchase table like this

```
purchase
---------
id_purchase
id_customer
id_product

customers            
-----------
id                           
name                    
mail                    
member_since            

products
------------
prod_nr 
name
price
quantity
```

Then your SQL would be:

```
SELECT * from customers JOIN purchase ON id = id_customer JOIN products ON prod_nr = id_product
ORDER BY DESC price
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Uhm. This only leads to an error in the database provider. I have added the segment that gives me problems, on the foreach loop. Don't know if it is the database provider or something else?

Comment: @HaraldOve you make the 3 tables?

Comment: Yes. Made the 3 tables, but no good :/ Get's a foreach error from the database provider...